# Using Prestashop's API

Tags: php, apache, wamp, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Assuming I have a file named categories.php.

When I add `require dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php'`and `require dirname(__FILE__).'/init.php'`

The problem is that this 2 requirements files are found but they load the homepage of the website. So when I echo'ed each field of a query, I can't see it.

Anyone could help me ?

Thanks

Comment: **SOLVED** See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43712311/dbinstance-prestashop/43722221#43722221

Answer (score 0):

Please try enabling the error debugging on your store, there must be an error (might be with file inclusion code) causing the problem.

FYI, to enable/disable debugging you can follow the steps below.

- open file: config/defines.inc.php (using FTP or hosting control panel)
- change true-->false:

define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);

define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false);